# Best way to extract Blob ( stored xml ) data from mySql database using SAS or mySQL or Excel ?

Tags: mysql, blob, extract, sas

What is the best way to extract mySQL Blob data into SAS dataset using mySQL or SAS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the SAS/ACCESS inteface to MySQL, then you could use a pass-through query or access the database through a LIBNAME statement.  SAS will read in the BLOB variable as a character string, so the variable length might be a limitation.

You can read more about how to do this at [SAS/ACCESS Interface to MySQL](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63144/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p02t4dkncyoxu7n1w2ysn79hm7em.htm).